execute lucene query in multiple language utilizing AI Model
We have requirement to support multiple language search for the same field. for example title is "Badminton" and subject is "sports" I want to search in solr like title:Badminton AND subject:sports. this simply works for english but how do i search same document if i use any other language like Thai. title:แบดมินตัน AND subject:กีฬา. Thai is just and example but I should be able to search in any worlds known langauge.
We did some POC on DenseVector field type where we convert string to DenseVector using HuggingFace AI Model "sentence-transformers/distiluse-base-multilingual-cased-v2" and storing vector data into field like
  <fieldType name="knn_vector" class="solr.DenseVectorField" vectorDimension="512" multiValued="true" similarityFunction="cosine"/>
<field name="title" type="knn_vector" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
<field name="subject" type="knn_vector" indexed="true" stored="true"/>

And after indexing data, we are executing KNN query to that field
But problem with this is , I can invoke KNN query to only one field at a time. As i showed lucene query where I can query two field at a time like title:แบดมินตัน AND subject:กีฬา. I cannot execute two KNN query for title and for subject.
if anyone see possibility to execute KNN query for multiple field then please let me know.
if if there is any other solution where I can target group of field for multiple language and if i can execute lucene like query then it will be a great help.
